# How to solve "Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scroll

I want to scroll to a particular div on clicking a button in **Angular 7**, below is the code I am using but it is working in stackblitz but showing error when i use in my project. 
"Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined".

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-local-variable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fscroll.component.ts

try this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-local-variable-ja96uz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
<button (click)="scroll(target)"></button>
<div #target>Your target</div>
```

and in component:

```
scroll(el) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Its working fine in StackBlitz

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yes it is working in stackblitz but showing error mentioned above in question when i use with html in different file and ts code in different.

Comment: I would suggest to create a stackblitz and post the current process to get help

Comment: @PrashantPimpale https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-local-variable-ja96uz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: @PrashantPimpale sorry, not working. link is not opening.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it is same as the first link i have provided in the question, the issue is I have html in different file than TS file and scroll is not working there.

Answer (score 4):

Try angular ViewportScroller Service Which provide scrollToAnchor method

**scroll.html**

```
<button (click)="scroll('target')">Click to scroll</button>
<div id="target">Your target</div>
```

**scroll.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'scroll',
  template: `
    <button (click)="scroll('target')">Click to scroll</button>
    <div id="target">Your target</div>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`, `div { margin-top: 5000px; }`]
})
export class ScrollComponent {

  constructor(private vps: ViewportScroller) {

  }
  scroll(id) {
    this.vps.scrollToAnchor(id);
  }
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-local-variable-99hwvo

Comment: i have tried and now it is showing "Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null"

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yes it is working in stackblitz but showing error mentioned above in question when i use with html in different file and ts code in different.

Comment: @Chellappan thanks error is not showing now but it is not getting scroll to the div i need.      i have this in my html >           line a:  <mat-radio-button  value="1" (click)="onButtonClick(); scroll('target');">Cash</mat-radio-button>      AND AT line b:  <div id="target">
  <ion-card *ngIf="buttonClicked">
//some data in card
  </ion-card>
</div>

Comment: @PrashantPimpale     i have this in my html >           line a:  <mat-radio-button  value="1" (click)="onButtonClick(); scroll('target');">Cash</mat-radio-button>      AND AT line b:  <div id="target">
  <ion-card *ngIf="buttonClicked">
//some data in card
  </ion-card>
</div>

Comment: @Chellappan your solution is not making page scrolled to the id given div. you can check here what i am trying to achieve. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-local-variable-ja96uz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: you are not using Viewportscroller

Comment: @Chellappan I had but with that too didn't provided the result. No scrolling was there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ViewChild:

```
//HTML 
<button (click)="scroll()"></button><div #target>Your target</div>


//ts

//Import
import { ..., ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

//Declare
@ViewChild('target') targetEl: ElementRef;

scroll() {
    this.targetEl.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: I tried and it is showing "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Scroll.html

```
<button (click)="scroll()">Click to scroll</button>
<div id="target">Your target</div>
```

componet.ts

```
getOffset(el) {
   el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
   return {
      left: el.left + window.scrollX,
      top: el.top + window.scrollY,
      bottom: el.top + window.scrollY
   }
}


scroll() {
    var scroll_to = document.getElementById('target');
    var topHight = this.getOffset(scroll_to).top;
    window.scrollTo(0, topHight);
  }
```

Comment: i tried this but it is not working can u please share stackblitz working of it?

Comment: can u please check ur link ?? it is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

The code is not working because of `*ngIf` condition, when you use `show` variable is default set to `false`, hence the <kbd>div</kbd> is not rendered on the component.

The code should be used in a related component where you want to scroll to be done, for example:

if you required in the scroll component then

HTML:

```
<button (click)="scroll(target)">clicking this button</button>
<div style="marging-top: 100px; height: 900px;"></div>
<div #target *ngIf="show" style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px;margin-top: 10px;">
show get screen scrolled to this div
</div>
```

TS:

```
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
   if(el){ // If the div is rendered on the HTML then it should be HTML element
     el.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-into-view)

Comment: this answer only for exception handler. but need a solution for that.

Comment: You must have checked the stackblitz, did you?